# Where can I find "MXC Video For Linux Camera" in buildroot menuconfig (i.MX6Q)?

Tags: qt, qt5, embedded-linux, buildroot, bsp

### Environment

I'm using Buildroot 'imx6-sabresd_qt5_defconfig', and adding 'openssh', 'gdb', some 'gstreamer' for playing video.

My board is i.MX6Q. I add ov5640 as module and use this command to install ov5640 module

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.14/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/ov5640.ko
```

### Test - Qt camera app

Then run Qt camera demo app, it showed this error

```
Unable to open the camera "" for read to query the parameter info: "No such file or directory" 
CameraBin error: "GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure."
```

Also, I added this code to show available cameras, it returned 0.

```
qDebug()<<QCameraInfo::availableCameras().count();
```

The error said I don't have available camera.
Then I find out I don't have this file:

```
 driver/media/video/mxc
```

### Question

Where can I find "MXC Video For Linux Camera" in buildroot? Is it in menuconfig or linux-menuconfig or I have to port the driver? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to assist:

get current kernel config:

```
cd /usr/src/"kernel version"

sudo zcat /proc/config.gz > /usr/src/"kernel version"/current.config

sudo make menuconfig
```

load current.config

```
>>>>drivers
>>>>>>>>>>>>multimedia
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>select all that apply here and under
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>v4l
```

many camera modules should be listed incuding sonyimx and 0V5640...

save as .config

sudo make zimage and replace....